# What is the most correct way to test modifiers?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, truffle, testing

As per the title, which testing method is most correct for modifiers? Something like testing via inheritance and creating a function specifically designed to test modifiers or testing via a framework like truffle (or even something else)? Just trying to get a better idea of Solidity best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The test framework you choose shouldn't matter. We use `truffle` and `solidity-coverage` to ensure test coverage. One example of a repo with 100% code coverage is https://github.com/JoinColony/colonySale

As an example for how modifiers are tested, see this `saleOpen` modifier
https://github.com/JoinColony/colonySale/blob/master/contracts/ColonyTokenSale.sol#L63 
used on the `buy` function.

We test this one specifically via negative test cases, e.g. 
https://github.com/JoinColony/colonySale/blob/master/test/colony-token-sale.js#L215